# CSS class for only "in between" class instances

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have some HTML like this.

```
<ul>blah</ul>
<li class="classOne">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classOne">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classOne">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
<li class="classTwo">blah></li>
</ul>
```

I want to have a border around each instance of classOne, but instances of classTwo should not have a border around them.

If I make the border-bottom invisible on instances of classTwo, then I'm effectively removing the top border of the next instance of classOne after an instance of classTwo.

Is there a CSS way of saying "only remove the bottom border of this element if the next element has the same class"?

Comment: Why don't you just have a full border around `classOne`? It would seem to work in your example. [is this not what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/fos58L3e/)

Comment: Agree with the above comment. It would be helpful if you can create a fiddle with your current code and give a demo of what your problem is.

Comment: @musefan i guess you didn't understand the question properly. He should've provided a fiddle, but the question is still understandable without it.

Comment: On further review. [This is probably more what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/5ew7otsc/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you declare borders around .classOne elements, they are not affected by any declaration regarding .classTwo

```css
.classOne {
  border:1px solid black}
.classTwo {
  /* This is not neccessary but explicit */
  border:none;
  }
```